# What is "SystemDBConnection"

Tags: c, sql-server, database, precompile, embedded-sql

I've to fix a problem in an old ANSI C program witch make use of Microsoft Embedded Precompiler (nsqlprep).
I come across the following line of code:

```
EXEC SQL CONNECT TO :DBName AS SystemDBConnection USER :DBLogin;
```

In the source it isn't defined, so I've searched for `SystemDBConnection` with Google but can't find anything about it.

Does anyone know what `SystemDBConnection` is?

Comment: `DBName AS SystemDBConnection` is the syntax for a synonym: the left will be known too AS the right part.

Comment: Is this synonym anywhere defined or can it be a free form text?

Comment: This __is__ the definition of the synonym.